# Does creating a table after the database has already been created change the database version in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I created an SQLite database for an Android application. The database originally had several tables.

On a particular application version, I added code that created a new table (i.e., db.execSQL("create table if not exists " + table_name ...) but never changed the database version from 1 on the SQLiteOpenHelper's constructor.

Now I want to upgrade the database. My **question** is:

**Would the existing modified database still be version 1 or did the database version number increment automatically when the new table was created (even though the database was not upgraded via the onUpgrade(...) method)?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What had prompted my question was the definition of the PRAGMA schema_version(http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_schema_version) which states that "the schema-version is usually only manipulated internally by SQLite. It is incremented by SQLite whenever the database schema is modified (by creating or dropping a table or index)." I take it that Android modifies the user_version instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you extend your SQLiteOpenHelper class you define which database version to use. For instance, in the following way:

```
private static class DbWordsHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private DbWordsHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }
```

If you upgrade your database you should change DB_VERSION manually in your code and rebuild your application. New version has to be higher then previous one. When SQLiteOpenHelper detects that your version number has been changed it calls onUpgrade method where you should provide logic how to update your database:

```
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        // Here in the future should be method that change the schema of the
        // database. Now we just delete
        try {
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE_WORDS);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error while updating database" + TABLE_WORDS, e);
        }

        onCreate(db);

    }
```

Thus, even if you add new tables the version is not changed until you manually do this in the code.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the information I was looking for. I guess the documentation I looked at wasn't clear but this is what I suspected. Once again, thank you for your response!

Answer (score 1):

It is database version, not table version. So, dropping/recreating table won't effect database version.

Comment: OK, thanks. I looked for documentation that explained this but could not find it.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29 if you check onUpgrade method, there you are passing version numbers and this will be called only cases where database upgrade needed.

Comment: OK, I had seen this but it was not completely clear to me whether the database version would increment with any changes to the database outside of onUpgrade(...). Anyhow, thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1):

database version is what you assigned in the SQLiteOPenHelper, now you have 2 different structured database with same version number, that's really BAD, and onUpgrade will never be called because the same version number.

Comment: Yep, I agree. But now I can fix it... I just wanted to know if the version had changed but you answered my question. Is there a link to either Android or SQLite documents that explains this? Thanks.